# How can I create two different isntance of connection to Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I need to have two different Facebook connection on the same website! So, they points to two different Application Keys.

How can I manage this?

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: One connection is for a sort of classics Social Networks Tools (same Api Key for each websites where I implement it). One should be specific for the website I'm working about, due to the fact I'm working with login/auth.

Comment: So basically, if I understand you correctly, you want the anility to work with n+1 fb apps, where the "+1" is your site, and the "n" is for sites that your main site can work with? Also, how are you planing to interact with facebook (for one of the "n" applications), client side and/or server side?

Comment: I can! I create an application with an ID, without references to any website (this is for the N website, for options like +1 or comments). For the login, I need to set up a url+canvas for the application, so I need a "solo" api key. That's my scenario...

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something [Facebook JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) supports and this can't be simply achieved by storing [`FB` object](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-js-sdk/blob/master/src/core/prelude.js) in other variable before adding another instance of SDK.

In the code of SDK `FB` is used directly pretty everywhere, and the response from API will use it too.

BTW, Even if it was possible your users would be needed to Authorize two applications if you want to access their data (transfer of data from one application to another violate platform policies).

Answer (score 0):

As @JuicyScripter wrote, the js sdk itself can not be shared among different apps in the same document, and that's exactly what you can try to play with.

How about adding an iframe per fb app?
You have the main page (the +1) which acts as usual, then you load an iframe inside of it and in it you can load another fb sdk for a different application.
Depending on what exactly you plan on doing, you might need to communicate between iframes, which will only work if they share the same domain.

Another approach is to make all api requests from the server side, but you'll have to have an access token for the user per app.